# Mongodb $match and $project aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this very simple set of documents.

```
> db.ysTest.aggregate({$project:{_id:1,unitStatus:1}});
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("514309f3e18aa7d14100217a"),
        "unitStatus" : "es_pws"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("514309f3e18aa7d141002816"),
        "unitStatus" : "es_run"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("514309f0e18aa7d14100021e")
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

When use 'aggregate' using $match & $project, i expect 1 document but i get them all.
note: I'm using aggregate because this is going to be part of a more complicated match, but i tried to keep it simple for this example.

```
> db.ysTest.aggregate({
... $match: {
...   unitStatus: {$exists: true, $nin: ["es_pws", "es_stl"]}
... },
... $project: {_id: 1,unitStatus:1}
... });
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("514309f3e18aa7d14100217a"),
        "unitStatus" : "es_pws"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("514309f3e18aa7d141002816"),
        "unitStatus" : "es_run"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("514309f0e18aa7d14100021e")
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: are you intending to group?  You need a {$group} stage to specify how you want to group the documents and what aggregation you want.

Comment: It's a subtle error, close the $match with another } before the comma and add a { before the $project and it will work the way you want it to:

db.ysTest.aggregate(  {$match: {unitStatus: {$exists:true, $nin: ["es_pws", "es_stl"]}} },  {$project:{_id: 1,unitStatus:1}} );

Comment: have you tried  just `unitStatus: {$exists: true}` to make sure

Comment: it's true that your syntax is not correct (brackets are misplaced) but if you fix that it works fine for me.  Your syntax would give an error though.  note how your don't have a '{' in front of $project - that makes it a field and not an aggregation operator and gives a syntax error.

Comment: Yes it's true... my syntax was completely wrong.
I was working with mongodb + nodejs driver and there things are a bit different, than in shell. Anyway that fixed my problem, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your document, query and the comments it is clear that you're not using `$group` operator and `$match` is simply a select clause which filter the result based on your given criteria. in your case

```
... $match: {
...   unitStatus: {$exists: true, $nin: ["es_pws", "es_stl"]}
... }
```

But `$match` and `$group` doesn't guarantee that it will return one document. what guarantee is your schema, query criteria.